# Prove an algebra isomorphism $K[\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}] \cong K[t]/(t^n-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, group-isomorphism

Let $n > 1$ be  an integer. How to prove an algebra isomorphism $$K[\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}] \cong K[t]/(t^n-1)?$$

Take $$K[\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}] = K[\overline{0}, \overline{1}, \ldots, \overline{n-1}] = \{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} k_i \overline{i}\mid k_i \in K\},$$
and
$$K[t]/(t^n-1) = \{ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} k_i t^i + (t^n-1) \mid k_i \in K\}.$$

I was trying to the case of $n=2$, $$\phi: K[\overline{0}, \overline{1}] \cong K[t]/(t^2-1).$$

If $\phi(\overline{1}) = t + (t^2-1)$, then $\phi(\overline{1}\cdot \overline{1}) = t^2 + (t^2-1) = 1 + (t^2-1) \neq \phi(\overline{1})$.  So  $\phi(\overline{1}) = \frac{1+t}{2} + (t^2-1)$.

Comment: Well, the form of elements of $K[\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}]$ and elements of $K[t]/(t^n-1)$ that you wrote looks suspiciously similar.  Does that suggest a map that you might try to prove is an isomorphism?

Comment: Consider mapping $\overline{i}\to t^{\overline{i}}$

Comment: @Mark Thank you. I have added my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining an isomorphism that sends $\overline{a}$ to $t^a+(t^n-1)$.  Remember that the group operation in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is what is normally written as addition, not multiplication.  This means that in $K[\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}]$, $\overline{a}\cdot\overline{b}=\overline{(a+b)}$, not $\overline{(a\cdot b)}$.  In your example with $n=2$ that gives $\overline{1}\cdot\overline{1}=\overline{0}$, which is compatible with defining $\phi(\overline{a})=t^a+(t^2-1)$.  Of course, you still must do more work to check that you really can define an isomorphism that way and that it works for any $n$.

Comment: This kind of glosses over the "prove it's an isomorphism", no?

Comment: Right, but from context it seems clear that the real question was not how to completely solve the problem but how to get over the obstacle that the obvious approach appeared not to work.